# Seeking free elevation data for Thailand/Bangkok?

Tags: data, dem

I am in the process of writing my thesis on flood hazard preparedness and forecasting in South East Asia, specifically Thailand. My analysis requires a medium resolution (even better, high resolution) digital elevation model for Bangkok and vicinity areas.

Where can I find such data?

My internet search so far returns not DEM data but only finished maps from different organizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest Aster DEM for your purpose. You can download 30MX30M DEM from [ASTER GDEM](http://gdem.ersdac.jspacesystems.or.jp/)